# Blender recalculate Vertex Position so no Group Transform Matrices are needed

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have a Model (I'm sorry I can't upload or show images of that). This Model is a huge bunch of group nodes and geometries and so on.

Some of the group have their own transform matrices and some are identity. This is normaly just fine and how it should be. I know that. But for my problem I need the model only to have ONE (or none) transform matrices in the head node and every other group node should have identity matrices. Is there a way to recalculate every vertex of the model and set all matrices to identity? So all vertex share the same "local space".

It would be super cool if there is something like that in Blender and somebody could explain how to do that.

Maybe this helps:

```
Model
- Group One Translation -2 0 0
  - Geometry Vertex 1 0 0
- Group Two Translation 5 0 0
  - Geometry Vertex 4 0 0
```

this should be converted to

```
Model
- Group One Translation 0 0 0
  - Geometry Vertex -1 0 0
- Group Two Translation 0 0 0
  - Geometry Vertex 9 0 0
```

Comment: Hi Noxxer (or NoxxKn?) welcome to Blender SE.  Blender's usual data structures aren't really represented by nodes, unless you're using something like Sverchok to model them parametrically.  Assuming you're not using nodes this way, I suspect you're looking at merging a number of different objects mesh objects into a single object, with one object transform(giving each vertex an identity relative to that origin).  Is this the case?

Comment: Sry i come from the programing side. xD

We call the structure of model a tree with nodes ... sry for that. : )

No the structure of the model should remain as it is. Only the coordinate systems of the whole model should be one. 

I have updated the question so it is more visible

Greets NoxxKn

Comment: No don't be sorry, even other 3d packages call it nodes.  If you want each object to recognize the same ultimate matrix without having to merge them, you need to parent them:https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Groups_and_Parenting

Answer (score 1):

Blender always has to have geometry wrapped in an Object datablock.  So the best way to achieve your Group X >> Geometry xx zeroed out is to parent Geometry xx to Group X Object, and then do an `Apply location` to Group X.  Without seeing a blend or a screenshot, I can't be anymore specific.

Comment: Thank you for your your reply. It was very kind of you. With the information i gave, you did what you could. I will try that and will mark the answer as the right one if it has worked. : )

Comment: No problem Noxxer, glad to help.